# ACF, Wordpress не отображаются доп поля при добавлении новых записей и при смене SLUG категорий

Tags: wordpress, acf

Плагином ACF создал доп поля. Назначил им категории, заполнил их у пары записей в категориях.
Затем через phpmyadmin запросами sql внёс значение этих полей для всех записей которым они полагаются(по аналогии с теми записями что заполнял через админку). Поля у всех записей в нужных категориях появились, редактируются в админке и отображаются во форонэнде нормально. Но создаю новую категорию, добавляю её в условия отображения допполей, пытаюсь создать в ней запись, поля не отображаются.

Переименовываю старую категорию(где поля корректно отображались), перевыбираю её в настройках ACF, доп.поля в админке в записях этой категории пропадают, во фронт энде отображаются по-старому.

Подскажите с чем может быть связано такое странное поведение ACF. Грешу конечно что в sql которыми вносил что-то накосячил, но делал по шаблону записей самого ACF.

---

Весь день сегодня пролазил по базе, удалил вообще всё что связано с этой группой полей, все записи в таблица wp_postmeta и wp_posts. Открываю старую запись на редактирование он мне всё равно предлагает доп поля которых уже нет ни в настройках компонента ни в БД, правда все поля уже пустые без заполненных значений. Я удивился, заполнил некотрые поля, сохранил, всё сохранилось в базе в wp_postmeta появились записи с именами тех полей и значениями, хотя откуда он их помнит имена полей для меня стало загадкой. Выбрал одно из полей и решил просто поискать эту фразу в базе, нет её нигде кроме этой записи. Взял тоже слово начал искать через тоталкомандер по файлам сайта и к моему удивлению в папке текущей темы находится файл dop_polya.php в файле код с этим полем

```
<?php 
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_5fd603027ac1e',
    'title' => 'Характеристики',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5fd6036218516',
            'label' => 'Характеристики',
            'name' => 'specifications',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'instructions' => '',
```

и этот файл подключен в function.php откуда взялся этот файл я пока не знаю, но удалив его и закоментировав его подключение дело хоть как-то продвинулось. Если кто знает как этот файл появляется и зачем проясните ситуацию. В самом компоненте ACF есть раздел инструменты и там есть генерация PHP но насколько я вижу просто нажатие этого файла не создаёт его в папке темы.

Comment: если есть у кого возможность помочь разобраться могу дать доступ в админку и базу

Comment: В базу залез sql-ем? Да ещё в метаполя.. Мои соболезнования. Читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562 (вторая причина)